# modify fflush() that guarantee calling ungetc() twice in a row in C

Tags: c, stdio, fflush, getc, ungetc

I'm a C beginner, I want to call ungetc() twice in a row although I know in regular C it is not permitted. Someone told me I can modify `Fflush()` to do this job, however I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code, my `Fflush` only allow one `ungetc()`, I want it to allow twice.

```
#define altUngetc(c, fp) ((fp)->next > (fp)->buffer && (c) != EOF ? \
 *--(fp)->next = (c) : EOF)

int altGetc(ALT_FILE *fp) {
  if (fp->next == fp->buffer + fp->bufSize)
  altFflush(fp);

  return fp->flags & FILE_ATEOF ? EOF : *fp->next++;
}

int altFflush(ALT_FILE *fp) {
  int res;

  if (fp->fd < 0 || fp->flags & FILE_ATEOF)
     return EOF;
  if (fp->flags & FILE_READ) {                               
     res = read(fp->fd, fp->buffer, BUF_SIZE);               
     if (res == 0)                                           
        fp->flags |= FILE_ATEOF;                             
     fp->bufSize = res;                                      
     fp->next = fp->buffer;                                  
  }                                                          
  else {                                                     
     res = write(fp->fd, fp->buffer, fp->next - fp->buffer); 
     fp->next = fp->buffer;                                  
  }   
   return res < 0 ? EOF : 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `fflush()` will serve that purpose. If I'm understanding correctly, you intend to do `ungetc()` twice, and get your code to be guaranteed to work, right? **Edit**: It doesn't undoes `ungetc()`'s effects. That means it's still uneffective for your purposes.

Comment: advice: as a C beginner, you should probably first learn to work with the rules instead of trying to break them.

Comment: yes, what I want is to modify original fflush() code. I think this is going to be a matter of arranging for at least two chars to be in the buffer to be "ungotten", no matter what.

Comment: @yuanwang: How is your code failing? It seems to me that you ought to be able to put up to `BUF_SIZE` characters read immediately after a `fflush` call back, though admittedly I haven't scrutinized it in detail. However a more reasonable approach would be to reserve as many characters as required of normally-unused extra space at the front the buffer which `ungetc` would be allowed to back up onto. Essentially `setvbuf(stream, &buffer[2], _IOFBF, sizeof buffer - 2)` except with custom buffering code crafted to cooperate.

Comment: @doynax: my original fflush() code only allow at least one char in buffer, so if I call two ungetc() consequently, it may fail. I think you are right, I need to put at least two chars in buffer, but I'm confused how to do it.

Comment: Note that while the C standard only guarantees one character of push-back with `ungetc()` (and it says the "use of ungetc on a binary stream where the file position indicator is zero prior to
the call is an obsolescent feature"), many implementations allow far larger amounts of push-back.  IIRC, an oldish AIX was the most parsimonious, only allowing 4 characters, while Linux and BSD allowed 4 KiB (possibly more; my testing stopped at 4 KiB).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Apparently, Glibc's implementation limit is a failed `malloc()`.

Answer (score 5):

As wisely mentioned in the comments, `you should probably first learn to work with the rules instead of trying to break them`. However, we're here to answer the question, and that means to break the rules! Take into account that neither `fflush()`, `setbuf()`, or `setvbuf()` would work here for different reasons.

First of all, at least four custom functions are required. One to create a "proxy buffer" relating to a file (called just after `fopen()`), one to destroy it (called just before `fclose()`, one to do the actual ungetting (replacement for `ungetc()`, and one to to retrieve a `char` from the file (replacement for `fgetc()`. Unfortunately, this means that performing `fscanf()`, `fflush()`, etc... on the stream will yield you bad and ugly results. You would have to rewrite all of `stdio`!

First of all, let's call all of our new stuff `xtdio` ("extended `stdio`"), so, first of all comes `xtdio.h`...

```
#ifndef __XTDIO_H__
#define __XTDIO_H__

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_size;
    size_t buffer_usage;
    size_t buffer_tail_offset;
} XFILE;

/* I know this is not the best of API design, but I need to be
 * compatible with stdio's API.
 */
XFILE *xwrap(FILE *file, size_t max_ungets);
void xunwrap(XFILE *xfile);
int xgetc(XFILE *xfile);
int xungetc(int ch, XFILE *xfile);

#endif
```

Then, in the interesting side of the fence, comes `xtdio.c`...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xtdio.h"

/* Create a XFILE wrapper, along with its respective buffer
 * of 'max_ungets' size, around 'file'.
 */
XFILE *xwrap(FILE *file, size_t max_ungets)
{
    XFILE *xfile = malloc(sizeof(XFILE));
    if(xfile == NULL)
        return NULL;

    xfile->file = file;
    xfile->buffer = malloc(max_ungets);
    if(xfile->buffer == NULL) {
        free(xfile);
        return NULL;
    }

    xfile->buffer_size = max_ungets;
    xfile->buffer_usage = 0;
    xfile->buffer_tail_offset = 0;

    return xfile;
}

/* Undo what 'xwrap()' did.
 */
void xunwrap(XFILE *xfile)
{
    free(xfile->buffer);
    free(xfile);
}

/* Check if there's something in the XFILE's
 * buffer, and return it. Otherwise, fallback
 * onto 'fgetc()'.
 */
int xgetc(XFILE *xfile)
{
    if(xfile->buffer_usage == 0)
        return fgetc(xfile->file);

    if(xfile->buffer_tail_offset == 0)
        xfile->buffer_tail_offset = xfile->buffer_size - 1;
    else
        xfile->buffer_tail_offset--;

    xfile->buffer_usage--;

    return xfile->buffer[xfile->buffer_tail_offset];
}

/* Here's the interesting part! If there's room in the
 * buffer, it puts 'ch' in its front. Otherwise, returns
 * an error.
 */
int xungetc(int ch, XFILE *xfile)
{
    if(xfile->buffer_usage == xfile->buffer_size)
        return EOF; //TODO: Set errno or something

    xfile->buffer[xfile->buffer_tail_offset++] = (char)ch;
    xfile->buffer_tail_offset %= xfile->buffer_size;
    xfile->buffer_usage++;

    return ch;
}
```

The smallish `xtdio` library will allow you to perform as many ungets as you pass to `xwrap()`'s parameter. Each `XFILE` has a buffer with the ungotten characters. When you `xgetc()`, it first checks if there's something on the buffer and retrieves it. Otherwise, it fallbacks to `fgetc()`. Example usage case...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "xtdio.h"

int main()
{
    const char *my_string = "I just ungot this same long string in standard and compliant C! No more one-char limits on ungetc()!\n";
    const size_t my_string_len = strlen(my_string);

    XFILE *xtdin = xwrap(stdin, my_string_len);
    if(xtdin == NULL) {
        perror("xwrap");
        return 1;
    }

    for(size_t i = my_string_len; i != 0; i--)
        xungetc(my_string[i - 1], xtdin);

    int ch;
    while((ch = xgetc(xtdin)) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);

    xunwrap(xtdin);
    return 0;
}
```

`xtdio` can be further improved, by adding things such as `xrewrap()` to extend/shrink the buffer's size.

There's an even better solution, and it is to refactor your code, and **follow the conventions**, so that you don't have to `ungetc()` twice. `xtdio` is just a proof of concept, but **is not good code, and shall never be used in practice**. This way, you won't have to deal with rewriting `stdio`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to implement a `int` stack, you can create your own `ungetc()` function. Simply replace calls of `ungetc()` with a `myungetc()` (etc) that if that stack has values, pop them instead of reading from `getc()`. Whenever you want to un-get, simply push values on to the stack in the reverse order you read them.

An example from a recent project of mine:

```
/* stack.h */
#ifndef _STACK_H_
#define _STACK_H_
typedef struct {
  int * vals;
  int currsize;
  int maxsize;
} stack;

int stack_init(stack * this, int size);
void stack_destroy(stack * this);

void push(stack * this, int val);
int pop(stack * this);
int isempty(stack * this);
int isfull(stack * this);
int size(stack * this);
int maxsize(stack * this);
#endif

/* stack.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"
#define THIS (this)
#define VALS (this->vals)
#define CURRSIZE (this->currsize)
#define MAXSIZE (this->maxsize)
int stack_init(stack * this, int size) {
  VALS = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  CURRSIZE = 0;
  MAXSIZE = size;
  if (!VALS) {
    return 1; /* alloc fail */
  }
  return 0; /* successful init */
}
void stack_destroy(stack * this) {
  free(VALS);
}

void push(stack * this, int val) {
  if (isfull(THIS)) {
    return;
  }
  VALS[CURRSIZE++] = val;
}
int pop(stack * this) {
  if (isempty(THIS)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return VALS[--CURRSIZE];
}
int isempty(stack * this) {
  return (CURRSIZE == 0);
}
int isfull(stack * this) {
  return (CURRSIZE == MAXSIZE);
}
int size(stack * this) {
  return CURRSIZE;
}
int maxsize(stack * this) {
  return MAXSIZE;
}
#undef THIS
#undef VALS
#undef CURRSIZE
#undef MAXSIZE

/* main.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

int stgetc(FILE * stream, stack * pushed) { /* The getc() equivalent */
  if (isempty(pushed)) {
    return getc(stream);
  } else {
    return pop(pushed);
  }
}

int stpush(int val, stack * pushed) { /* The ungetc() equivalent */
  if (isfull(pushed)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    push(pushed,val);
    return 0;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  /* startup code, etc. */
  stack pushbuf; /* where the pushback will be stored */
  stack_init(&pushbuf, 32) /* 32 = maximum number of ungetc calls/characters we can push */
  FILE * in = fopen("/some/file","r");
  /* file read */
  int readchar;
  while ((readchar = stgetc(in,pushbuf)) != EOF) {
    /* do stuff */
    stpush(readchar,pushbuf); /* oops, read too much! */
  }
  fclose(&in); /* close file */
  stack_destroy(&pushbuf); /* clean up our buffer */
  /* ... */
}
```

(I apologize for the wall of text but a shorter example isn't possible)
Considering you seem to be working with a file, it should be possible to `fseek()` backwards, although this will work for both files and `stdin`.